# k6 default output in docker image is too big

Tags: k6

I'm running a k6 docker image with some tests.
However, the output that I get is very different from what I would expect.

[image]

Instead of the usual output with just summary, I get those annoying `running` and `default` prints.

How can I show just the end of test summary?

Answer (score 0):

Those console messages can be suppressed with the `-q` / `--quiet` flag as documented [here](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/options/#quiet).